# Division of polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I have a question that always seems to confuse me. Let's say for example I have a linear and quadratic equation.Do we say that the linear equation divides the quadratic, or vice versa. (Assuming that one does divide the other)

Thank you

Comment: You are dividing *polynomials*, not *equations*. You should replace "equation" by "polynomial" above.

Answer (score 1):

If one divides the other, then the "smaller" divides the "bigger". Just like $2$ divides $4$, not the other way around.

In fact, the concept of divisions is a concept inherent in all rings, not only whole numbers. In any ring $R$, we say that $x\in R$ divides $y\in R$ if there exists such a $k\in R$ that $$xk = y.$$
It is trivial to see that this matches divisability on the whole numbers.

It is also simple to see (in the case when you deal with polynomials with real coefficients) that polynomials of degree $n$ can only ever divide polynomials of degree $m\geq n$. This is because for a polynomial $p(x)$ of order $n$, any polynomial $k(x)$ of degree $m$ will cause the polynomial $p$ to have degree $m+n$.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial of lower degree may divide the polynomial of higher degree.

A polynomial of degree one: $\,f(x) = mx + b\,$ may divide a polynomial of degree two: $\;g(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, but not vice versa.

(And it also makes sense to say that if given two polynomials of equal degree, one might divide the other: e.g. $f(x) = x^2$ divides $f(x) = 2x^2$.)